# Not able to hit endpoint of class annotated with @Service and method inside it annotated with @Path using mockito

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito, jax-rs

I have class in my project that is annotated with **@Path** annotation and below is the code snippet

Annotations used in my class:

```
@Slf4j
@Service
@Path("/manageOffer")
@Api("Manage Services")
public class BffProductOfferServiceApi implements RestService {
```

Method in above class:

```
@POST
@Path("/fetchOfferDetails")
@ApiOperation(value = "Get offer details")
@ApiResponses(value = {@ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Ok", response = BffOfferDetails.class)})
//@TLogger(appName = "BFF", source = "APP2BFF",skipRequestResponseDownstream=true)
@LogMetric(enableMetrics = true,metricName = "metric_server_request",apiName = "fetchOfferDetails", customTags = {"flow","magenta"})
public BffOfferDetails fetchOfferDetails(@RequestBody BffOfferDetails offerDetails,
```

My task is to write test for this particular class.
Below is my test method which I have written. If I try to hit the above end-point(annotated with @Path) it is not being hit and gives **404 client error**. Below is the test snippet which I have written.

```
@Test
@DisplayName("Positive case: when all required  params are passed and response code is 200")
public void fetchOfferDetailsControllerStatus2XX() throws Exception {

    BffOfferDetails offerDetails = new BffOfferDetails();

    this.mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/manageOffer/fetchOfferDetails")
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .content(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(offerDetails))
                    .characterEncoding("utf-8")
                    .queryParams(queryParams)
                    .header("x-tenant","de"))
            .andDo(print())
            .andExpect(result -> result.getResponse())
            .andExpect(status().is2xxSuccessful());
}
```

Now to debug whether there is error in my test method or not, I made a separate TestController(Just to verify if I have written the tests correctly or not). This TestController is annotated with **@RestController.**

```
@RestController
public class TestController {
    @Autowired
    TestService testService;

    @PostMapping(value = "api1/getText")
    public BffOfferDetails getText(@RequestBody BffOfferDetails offerDetails){

        return testService.getText(offerDetails);
    }
```

I also wrote test for the above class annotated with @RestController. Below is the test method
To my surprise the below test **works fine as expected**

```
@Test
@DisplayName("Positive case: when all required  params are passed and response code is 200")
public void testSampleControllerStatus2XX() throws Exception {

    BffOfferDetails offerDetails = new BffOfferDetails();

    this.mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/api1/getText")
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .content(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(offerDetails))
                    .characterEncoding("utf-8"))
            .andDo(print())
            .andExpect(result -> result.getResponse())
            .andExpect(status().is2xxSuccessful());
}
```

Following are the annotations which I am using on my Test Class.

```
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc(addFilters = false)
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class BffProductOfferServiceApiTest{

}
```

**Note:** I am using Mockito for writing my tests.

What I have concluded from above is: @Path is uses jax-rs specifications, whereas @Restcontroller does not.

**My question is How should I write my tests such that classes annotated with @Service and methods annotated with @Path works correctly.**

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue... did you find the solution?